# Google Maps API and JQuery Slide Toggle not initialising map correctly

Tags: jquery, google-maps

The issue I am having is with the initialisation of the Google maps api. When I have the maps api in a normal div that is set to be displayed it works perfectly and toggles up and down but when I set the display to none it does not load correctly. The map only loads half way down and the pin image is not displayed. Is there a work around for this or will this simply not function in a toggle slide that is initially not displayed.

The example page I have created is as below.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jscripts/jquery-1.4.js'></script>

<style type="text/css">
.slideTogglebox{
    float:left;
    padding:8px;
    margin:16px;
    border:1px solid red;
    width:500px;
    height:350px;
    background-color:#000000;
    color:white;
    display:none;
}
.clear{
    clear:both;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
<?php
$url ="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address=PL329YN&sensor=false";
$getAddress = simplexml_load_file($url);
$lat = $getAddress->result->geometry->location->lat;
$lng = $getAddress->result->geometry->location->lng;
?>

<div class="clear">
<h3>slideToggle() example</h3> <a href="javascript:slideToggle()" id=slideToggle>Click Me</a>
<br/>
<div class="slideTogglebox" id='map_canvas'>

</div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

function initialize() {

    <?php
    print "var lat = $lat;";
    print "var lng = $lng;";
    ?>

    var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: latlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

    var image = 'images/map/pin_green.png';
    var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatLng,
        map: map,
        icon: image
    });
}

var init = false;

$("#slideToggle").click(function () {

   if (!init) {
        initialize();
        init = true;
   }
   $('.slideTogglebox').slideToggle('slow');
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be an issue with the new v3 api and jquery. It does seem to work with the v2 of the Google maps api without issue.

Therefore to fix the problem I have called the initialize function from after the div toggles. Then I have set the background in the CSS to match the background on the page so that it appears to fadein after the toggle.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$("#slideToggle").click(function () {

   $('.slideTogglebox').slideToggle(function initialize() {

        <?php
        print "var lat = $lat;";
        print "var lng = $lng;";
        ?>

        var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 10,
            center: latlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), myOptions);

        var image = 'images/map/pin_green.png';
        var myLatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
        var beachMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatLng,
            map: map,
            icon: image
        });
    });
});


</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It would *seem* the answer may be straightforward.  Initialize the map only when the div that is to contain the map is visible.  Put a callback into the `.slideToggle()` invocation check e if div is visible and there's no map. If so, load map (you may want to disable the click event actions while the map is loading, too).      You also might want to consider  making the map_canvas a child of the slideToggleBox (instead of the slideToggleBox itself) just in case that effects how the map reacts, etc.

BTW, what's with the `<a href="javascript:slideToggle()" ... >`  when you're already adding a click event via jQuery?

Answer (score 0):

You could also just animate the css (opacity, height) without using an extra callback in js. Works like a charm. As long as the div, containing the map, is displayed block, you're fine with this method.